# How to get keywords search volume using google Ads API without creating a keyword plan?

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api, ads-api

I want to get keywords' historical metrics using google Ads API, but I must create a keyword plan and get the data, but it also has other keyword suggestions which is not needed. Currently am using keyword idea endpoint in which the given keyword is the first row with data.
How to use the historical metrics endpoint without creating a keyword plan?

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-historical-metrics